# css: tab style border with background

Tags: html, css, background, border

Tell me, can I set the background to the border formed in the following way?

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lous8vq/1/

```
.object {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0px;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    background: transparent;
}

.object:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: calc(2.45px - 50px);
    width: calc(300px - 2 * 1.4px);
    height: 0px;
    border-left: 49px solid transparent;
    border-right: 49px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: calc(100px - 2px) solid white;
    background: transparent;
}

<div class="object"></div>
```

It's probably worth using the custom `border-image`, but it seemed to me that this still does not have enough functionality.

I want instead of a white color on the tab to display the image background (for example, https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/02/17/39/texture-1878273__340.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple background and gradient:

```css
.object {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff 49%,red 49%,red 51%,transparent 0) 100% 0/40px 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,#fff 49%,red 49%,red 51%,transparent 0) 0 0/40px 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0/100% 2px no-repeat,
  url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/02/17/39/texture-1878273__340.jpg)0 0/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='object'></div>
```

Another idea with clip-path:

```css
body {
 background:yellow;
}

.object {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom:none;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0/100% 2px no-repeat,   
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,red 51%,transparent 51.5%) 100% 0/60px 100%  no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 51%,transparent 51.5%) 0 0/60px 100%  no-repeat,   
  url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/02/17/39/texture-1878273__340.jpg)0 0/cover no-repeat;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='object'></div>
```

**UPDATE**

Another way more supported that rely on more elements:

```css
body {
 background:yellow;
}
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.object {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom:none;
  font-size:0;
}
.object .left,
.object .right {
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  border-top:2px solid red;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.object .left {
  border-left:2px solid red;
  transform:skew(-20deg);
  transform-origin:bottom left;
}
.object .right {
  border-right:2px solid red;
  transform:skew(20deg);
  transform-origin:bottom right;
}
.object .left:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-20px;
  bottom:0;
  right:-20px;
  transform:skew(20deg);
  background:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/02/17/39/texture-1878273__340.jpg); 
}
.object .right:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-20px;
  bottom:0;
  right:-20px;
  transform:skew(-20deg);
  background:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/02/17/39/texture-1878273__340.jpg); 
}
```

```html
<div class='object'>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! But...
1) `linear-gradient`is compatible with the Edge, Chrome, FF etc and it is good, but left & right white corner - it is problem (if body background is not white)  2) `clip-path` - very good command, but it is not compatible with Microsoft Edge :(

Comment: @Zhihar gradient are supported everywhere ;) ...and for the white border that's why i added the clip-path idea :)

Comment: buton `clip-path` not supported in Microsoft Edge :( (https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

Comment: @Zhihar added another way ;)